# Visual Studio code folding not working properly

Tags: visual-studio

does someone already has experienced this "issue" on visual studio?
it did not fold the code on the brackets, just on the function header, should have a `-` on line 32,35 like on the line 25

[image]

Comment: This happens to me often. It's so annoying. Somehow it keeps getting disabled and don't know how.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem with python code.
For me this helped:

File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Folding Strategy -> Set to "indentation"

"Folding Strategy - Controls the strategy for computing folding ranges"

This was set to "auto" for me, after changing to "indentation" it works.

I suspect the "auto" setting uses something smarter which may break depending on system, environment and used imports.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, I had this issue for a long time, which this change solved my problem. I think what does 'auto' do should be revised by vs-code developers. it is definitely a bug.

Comment: One particular .tsx file I had open, No folding arrow was visible, after changing from auto->identation, now it is visible and working, thanks.

Comment: It's still showing wrong foldings

Answer (score 5):

There is a setting in the VS.Code : "Settings / Editor: Folding Strategy" I set this to "indentation" while other option is only "auto".

I guess there sometimes problems with other extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's strange.

You can try a couple things:

- Re-opening the IDE.
- Try that piece of code somewhere else (to discard a more general issue).

Does it happen anywhere else? If it does, it could be an editor option.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C\C++- > View and set Outline Statement Blocks to true

I dont know how, but i had this option as false.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the outlining and then start it back up, it should refresh/reset the outlining data for that file.

```
first goto Edit->Outlining->StopOutlining
then goto  Edit->Outlining->StartAutomaticOutlining
```

This fixed my issue with code folding wrong code sections, and just doing weird stuff.

I made an extention for Visual Studios 2022 to do it in one click, because I was bored.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zachwuzhere.ext123

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the solutions posted so far to no avail. I ended up copying and pasting the code to a new file and the folding worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found my setting for "Editor: Folding" was false! i.e disabled. (I don't recall why)

Make sure it's on, i.e enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had something similiar.
At work it turned oud theme dracula had a bug hiding the fold line dark   ..